# AppleScript: move cursor (up/down arrow) – with repeat loop

Tags: applescript, arrow-keys

I’m trying to write an AppleScript to insert ["some text"] above ["found text"].

Here is what I wrote:

```
tell application "BBEdit"
   activate
   find "====" searching in text 1 of text document 1 with selecting match
   key code 126 # Up Arrow
   key code 126 # Up Arrow
   keystroke "<tabhere>"
   key code 125 # Down Arrow
   key code 125 # Down Arrow
   key code 125 # Down Arrow
end tell
```

I get the following error, with the first instance of "code" highlighted:

"Expected end of line, etc. but found identifier"

Following suggestion by @red_menace, I amended as follows:

```
tell application "BBEdit"  
    activate  
    find "====" searching in text 1 of text document 1 with selecting match  
    tell application "System Events"  
        key code 126 # Up Arrow  
        key code 126 # Up Arrow  
        keystroke "<tabhere>"  
        key code 125 # Down Arrow  
        key code 125 # Down Arrow  
        key code 125 # Down Arrow  
    end tell  
end tell
```

… which works, but of course only once.

Now how can I get this into a repeat loop that runs until the end of the document? The following attempt runs amok (it caused my computer to cycle wildly through all open windows in all applications and I had to fore quit):

```
tell application "BBEdit"
    activate
    repeat
        find "====" searching in text 1 of text document 1 with selecting match
        set findClass to find "====" searching in text 1 of text document 1 with selecting match
        if not found of findClass then exit repeat
        tell application "System Events"
            key code 126 # Up Arrow
            key code 126 # Up Arrow
            key code 48 # Tab
            key code 125 # Down Arrow
            key code 125 # Down Arrow
            key code 125 # Down Arrow
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

Thanks for any further help.

Comment: `key code` is a **System Events** command.

Answer (score 0):

BBedit can replace text without keystrokes

```
tell application "BBEdit"
   tell front document
      replace "===" using "---" & return & "===" options {wrap around:true}
   end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thx 4 this. Can BBEdit also directly accept arrow keys? For what I need is not to replace the found "====", but to insert a tab _two_ lines above "====", leaving the line directly above in place.